# How to select gridview cells by dragging the mouse over it

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Please i have a gridview with textbox template fields. I want if i drag the mouse on the gridview then those cells get selected just like how excel works. How do i achieve that.
Thank you.

Comment: please, provide more information on the context, your exact problem, etc: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)